# Systemd services inconsistent across Centos servers

Tags: centos7, systemd

We have a cluster of Centos 7.2 servers which have their installation managed by Ansible and packages managed by Katello. They should all be identical.

Despite this, there are a number of inconsistencies within the systemd services:

- dbus-org.freedesktop.import1.service: Some have static, some have nothing.
- dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service: Some have bad, some have invalid
- dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.service: some have nothing, some have enabled
- oddjobd.service: some are enabled, some are disabled
- autovt@.service: some are enabled, some are disabled.

---

- os-startup-event.service: most have nothing, two have static
- os-shutdown-event.service: most have nothing, two have disabled
- selinux-policy-migrate-local-changes@.service: most have nothing, two have disabled

---

- systemd-readahead-done.service: half have static, half have indirect
- sssd-secrets.service: half have static, half have indirect
- systemd-importd.service: half nothing, half static

The bottom two clusters are on the same machines.

So my questions are:

Which can I safely disable, which can I remove, which should I enable?

My initial reactions have been to remove them all as unnecessary.

Comment: None of these matter much, except possibly for the firewall. It's a bit worrying that you don't configure the firewall on some of your systems.

Comment: We have another team that runs a organisation wide enterprise grade firewall.

Comment: Ahh! Hard on the outside, soft and vulnerable on the inside. What I found strange, though, is that you say _some_ of the systems have a host firewall and some don't. Aren't you configuring firewalld explicitly with ansible?

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you were talking about - when I did the first install on this set of servers, the firewall service was called firewalld, and that's disabled by ansible. Only four machines from 40 have dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1. 
Where are all of these services coming from?

Comment: For eg. on systems that otherwise look identical, I'm getting two different results - bad and invalid - to the command `systemctl list-unit-files dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service`

both point to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service`, both of which are a broken symlink to the non existent `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service`. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.socket` exists?

Comment: ah! Different versions of systemctl. both returned 219 when interrogated with --version, but yum info shows me some are using .19 and some are using .30. hmm..